# Coercing mathematica to symbolically evaluate a spherical polar curl expression?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm attempting *Mathematica* programming, and thought I'd try a calculation that I did by hand manually (a magnetic field phasor calculation from an E&M class), using spherical polar coordinates.  I've created a variable and tried to take it's curl:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
SetCoordinates[Spherical]
SetAttributes[ k, Constant ]
eE := {0, 0, (Sin[Ttheta]/Rr) ( 1 - I/(k Rr)) e^{I k Rr}}
Curl[ eE ]
```

This doesn't actually evaluate the derivatives like I thought it would, giving only:

```
                I k Rr
               e       (-I + k Rr) Sin[Ttheta]
\[Curl]{0, 0, {-------------------------------}}
                      2
                  k Rr
```

Basically, it is just spitting my input back out to me as output.  `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` don't change the result.

One guess that I had was that this was because I hadn't specified k as a constant so I added that (as above), but this didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `e^{I k Rr}` to `E^(I k Rr)`.

1. `{}` means a vector, and Mathematica accepts vectors for all its functions, but outputs a vector, which is not what you want. For example, `e^{1,2,3}` becomes `{e^1, e^2, e^3}`. Thus the way you written the expression you have a one element list in position three of the first list, which throw Mathematica off.
2. The constant *e* is `E` in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks.  I had naively assumed the input syntax was latex like.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

First, in Mathematica the symbol `E`, not `e`, is the exponential constant *e*.

Second, you're raising `E` to the power of a list (`{...}`, aka `List[...]`), where I think you instead meant to use parens:

```
In[17]:= eE:={0,0,(Sin[Ttheta]/Rr) (1-I/(k Rr)) E^(I k Rr)}
In[18]:= Curl[eE]

Out[18]= {(2 E^(I k Rr) (1-I/(k Rr)) Cos[Ttheta])/Rr^2, (Csc[Ttheta]
  (-I E^(I k Rr) k (1-I/(k Rr)) Sin[Ttheta]^2-(I E^(I k Rr) 
  Sin[Ttheta]^2)/(k Rr^2)))/Rr,0}
```

HTH!

Comment: What is the easiest way to plot this field?

Comment: I think [`VectorPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VectorPlot3D.html) and a change-of-coordinates is one option: `k = 10; VectorPlot3D[curl /. Thread[{Rr, Ttheta, Pphi} -> CoordinatesFromCartesian[{x, y, z}]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`

Comment: Works like a charm. Never used Coordinates...[ ] like that. Seems very useful. Thanks.